# Groovy in operator not seeming to call isCase

Tags: groovy, operator-overloading

From what I've read, the Groovy `in` operator calls `isCase`. However, I've had a little problem recently and it goes like this:

```
class Test {}

new Test() in Test
```

This returns `true`. But when I switch it up to be:

```
class Test {}

new Test().isCase(Test)
```

It returns `false`. I don't understand the reasoning and cause behind this exactly, and I'm sort of afraid the `in` operator is hardcoded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`in` is a membership operator and is equivalent to calling `isCase()` method. So according to groovy doc:

> The membership operator (`in`) is equivalent to calling the `isCase`
>   method. In the context of a `List`, it is equivalent to calling
>   `contains`, like in the following example:
>
> `def list = ['Grace','Rob','Emmy']
>   assert ('Emmy' in list)`
>
> equivalent to calling `list.contains('Emmy')` or `list.isCase('Emmy')`

So in your case it would be:

```
Test t = new Test()

println t in Test
println Test.isCase(t)
```

And it would print true in both cases. You are getting false as you are calling the method on wrong object: `t.isCase(Test)`